# Schema.org PriceSpecification with a sale price

Tags: schema, schema.org, google-shopping

I'm currently building a Schema.org template for an ecommerce website, for the purposes of generating a Google Shopping Feed.

I'm struggling to understand the correct way to define a sale price - i.e. a product which has a temporary reduced price.

The options I've considered areL

- a single "Offer" with multiple "PriceSpecification" items
- multiple "Offer" items with a single "PriceSpecification"
- or maybe something else completely?

**Single "Offer" with multiple "PriceSpecification" items**

```
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "url": "https://kx.com/url",
    "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/UsedCondition",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "PriceSpecification": [
      {
        "@type": "PriceSpecification",
        "price": 15.00,
        "priceCurrency": "USD"
      },
      {
        "@type": "PriceSpecification",
        "price": 15.00,
        "priceCurrency": "USD",
        "validFrom": "2020-01-01",
        "validThrough": "2020-02-01",
      }
    ],
  },
```

**Multiple "Offer" items with a single "PriceSpecification"**

```
  "offers": [
    {
      "@type": "Offer",
      "url": "https://kx.com/url",
      "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/UsedCondition",
      "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
      "PriceSpecification": [
        {
          "@type": "PriceSpecification",
          "price": 15.00,
          "priceCurrency": "USD"
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "@type": "Offer",
      "url": "https://kx.com/url",
      "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/UsedCondition",
      "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
      "PriceSpecification": [
        {
          "@type": "PriceSpecification",
          "price": 15.00,
          "priceCurrency": "USD",
          "validFrom": "2020-01-01",
          "validThrough": "2020-02-01",
        }
      ],
    }
  ]
  },
```

Or is it something completely different? I'm struggling to find any conclusive documentation around this.

Comment: Have you checked these on GSDTT? The first scenario will not work IMHO. A subset of the first and second PriceSpecification statements are identical. You need to expose two distinct statement. A reduction (sale price) represents a change from time 1 to time 2. Set time 1 to "yesterday" and set time 2 to a range beginning "today". The price change is related to a past event (unless you are advertising the price reduction will be in the future, in which case no one will purchase until then).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd note that Google strongly recommends the `priceValidUntil` value on `Offer`. I also usually use the rule of thumb that your Structured Data should match what's in your markup, so I think the starting point of the sale is likely unnecessary, especially for a Google shopping feed.

If I were approaching this, I feel the safe route would be updating your `Product` structured data along with the content on the day of the sale, using the `priceValidUntil` field to note when that sale ends, then removing the attribute and updating the price once that date hits. You'd end up with something like:

```
 "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "url": "https://kx.com/url",
    "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/UsedCondition",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "price": 15.00,
    "priceCurrency": "USD",
    "priceValidUntil": "2/1/2020"
  }
```

In this example, on 2/1/2020 the `priceValidUntil` attribute would be removed and the `price` attribute would update, along with the content on the page.

Your first example does validate in the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool), but I don't think it will do you any good. I can see where you might want to advertise a sale ahead of time, but as far as I know a Google Shopping Feed/Carousel does not announce sales that are *going* to happen - just prices that *are* happening.

A final note that while `priceSpecification` does validate on the testing tool and is applicable to a product, details around it seem a bit vague and I'd be hesitant in expecting it to provide much value. [priceSpecification on schema.org](https://schema.org/PriceSpecification) has no example of it being used in a product (although again, not to say that means it is wrong).